# Splitting in number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime not dividing $n$  and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)\subset \mathbb{Q}(e^\frac{2 \pi i}{n})$. TFAE:

1)$\sigma _p(\sqrt d)=\sqrt d$($\sigma_p$ is Frobenius automorphism )

2)$p$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$

3)$(\frac{d}{p})=1$

Comment: What is $\sigma_p$? Also, isn't $\mathbf Q(\mathrm e^{2\pi i})$ the same as $\mathbf Q$?

Comment: @Bernard it was edited.

Comment: What facts/pieces of theory are we allowed to use when answering? It is kinda difficult to give a meaningful answer without knowing that. I believe many users call that *context*.

Comment: Anyway, items 1,2,3 can all be thought of as manifestations of the restriction of $\sigma_p$ to $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ being the identity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen as basic as possible I appreciate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you explain it for item 2?

Comment: $p$ doesn't ramify in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ so it is either inert or it splits. If it is inert, then...